# Submitting data instead of a file for an input form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to retrieve an image and post it to another form:

```
handler = function(data, status) {
    ...
    var fd;
    fd = new FormData;
    fd.append("file", data);
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: target_url,
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: "POST",
      complete: function(xhr, status) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(xhr.statusCode);
      }
    });
};
jQuery.get(imageUrl, null, handler);
```

The form looks something like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="file" name="file" />
  ...
</form>
```

Things aren't working as expected. I'm getting a 200 response from the server side, and it renders the forms with some of the values pre-populated.

I've also tried setting `contentType: "multipart/form-data"`

Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending a string which will not be recognized as a file.
Try sending a blob

```
fd.append("file", new Blob([data], { "type" : "text/plain" }));
```

I'm pretty sure this will only work for text files, unless you set the responseType on the original request.

Comment: Hmm. If this is an image, do I need to set the type accordingly? "image/png", etc.

Comment: Well, that certainly did something. Thanks :) Now I just have to figure out why the size of the image has changed. Original image size 15k, data submitted = 35k :/

Comment: @jabalsad the size changed because the image data was converted to text to prevent this you'll have to set the `responseType` property of the XMLHttpRequest object (to blob).

Comment: jQuery's ajax method doesn't allow Blob response types. Is it necessary to use XMLHttpRequest directly? Seems like an arbitrary limitation.

Comment: @jabalsad well you cant use `$.get` but I'm sure you can do it with `$.ajax`.

Comment: according to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ dataType can only be html, xml, json, text, script

Comment: @jabalsad I was talking about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#responseType

Comment: Hmmm I see. But basically that means I'll have to use XMLHttpRequest directly instead of jQuery's .ajax() method. Thanks, I'll have to hack a bit to see if I can get it working.

Comment: @jabalsad you can use `xhrFields` to set properties on the native xhr object

Comment: Ah neat! I'll definitely try that

Comment: I had to set the responseType on the XHR object using the beforeSend callback function (looks like the connection needs to be open first). But the data passed into the handler is still a string (by running `data.constructor`).

Comment: @jabalsad yeah I tried too but failed, you'll have to use native XMLHttpRequest then