# Load Jpeg image from MVC Controller via Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have the below Controller action

```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Image()
  {

     FileContentResult result;

     var bmp = SomeBitmap;

     using (var memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
     {
        bmp.Save(memStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        result = File(memStream.GetBuffer(), "image/jpeg");
     }
     return result;
  }
```

I have the following ajax call

```
function getImage() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Image", "Recordings")',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'image/jpg',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            Alert('never gets here');
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

**Issue**

Error returns parseError and 'No conversion from text to image/jpg'

Am i missing something here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a similar call in MVC. I think using ToArray() on the memory stream will solve your issue. I looked up the MSDN documentation and in the remarks section, it indicate that GetBuffer() will return to you extra unused bytes in the buffer. ToArray() will only return you the data that was actually written to in the buffer. Here is the MSDN link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: result = File(memStream.ToArray(), "image/jpeg"); has the same results unfortunatly

Comment: I wonder if the ajax call is reaching your controller method. Your controller method is near identical to mine with the ToArray() method in use (I used a png image instead). Try getting the actual URL in the ajax call and enter it into a new browser window. That should give you a clue on what is going on with that call.

Comment: Ahh ok that shows the image when i paste the raw url

Comment: I found a discussion on your issue on this site. Apparently you have to go away from JQuery. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657184/using-jquerys-ajax-method-to-retrieve-images-as-a-blob

Comment: Ok thanks, i ended up getting this working with dynamic html, however ill test this out, if it works i might get you to paste the javascript in your answer, to make it a little more concise