# Content-Security-Policy object-src blob

Tags: google-chrome, blob, content-security-policy

When using a content-security-policy and I try to follow a process in Chrome 41 (beta) using [window.URL.createObjectURL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17682424/19212) I get an error like the following:

> Refused to load plugin data from 'blob:http%3A//localhost%3A7000/f59612b8-c760-43a4-98cd-fe2a44648393' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "object-src blob://*"

With a content security policy that restricts `object-src` or otherwise `default-src` one can reproduce the issue (with jQuery for convenience) like this:

```
blob = new Blob(
   ["%PDF-1.\ntrailer<</Root<</Pages<</Kids[<</MediaBox[0 0 3 3]>>]>>>>>>"],
   { type: "application/pdf" })
$("<embed>").attr("src", window.URL.createObjectURL(blob))
  .appendTo(document.body)
```

It seems from [the spec that this should work](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#match-source-expression), as it does for `data://*`. I have tried also `blob`, `blob:`, `blob:*`, `blob:http*`, `blob:http:*`, `blob:http://*`, but to no avail.

What does work, but for apparent reasons is undesirable, is `object-src *`.

Has anyone had any success getting blobs to load with a content security policy? Is this a problem upstream, or have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The spec compliant answer is `object-src 'self' blob:`

`blob:` should only match `blob:` explicitly, and not `'self'` or `*`. This is a bug in [Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=473904), and was recently fixed in [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1086999) 40.

Comment: how to set in Tomcat?