# How to show a recovered Blob from PouchDB attachment as ngSrc?

Tags: angularjs, pouchdb

I am having a hard time showing a blob as `ngSrc` following the [PouchDB's Working with attachments Page](https://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments.html#image-attachments). My pertinent html is:

```
<img src="" ng-src="{{$root.images.myImgNameX}}" alt="">
```

it gets compiled into this:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8100/fcba0867-bf49-4fe0-b4f2-3490bb65761f" ng-src="blob:http://localhost:8100/fcba0867-bf49-4fe0-b4f2-3490bb65761f" alt="">
```

But the image is not showed. But if I copy and paste the url in `ng-src` I can see the image.
I get this error:

> :8100/#/app/news:1 Refused to load the image 'blob:http://localhost:8100/754f38af-0246-4b33-85c9-049f6d9ce1df' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: *".

How can I use that `blob` in my `img` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution looking into the error here : [Content-Security-Policy object-src blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467789/content-security-policy-object-src-blob)

I Added `img-src 'self' blob:` to my `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy">` tag