# Get data using image URL from AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, html, exif

I have the following AJAX call for getting images from a local directory :

```
var imagesArray = [];
$.ajax({
            url: "./images/",
            success: function(data){
            $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function(){
            var images = $(this).attr("href");
            imagesArray.push(images);
            });
            for(var i=0;i<imagesArray.length;;i++)
            {
        var str = 'images/'+imagesArray[i];                 
         $('<li class="slide">').append($('<img />').attr('src',str )).appendTo('#slider');
                }
            }
            });
```

and my HTML code is:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="imageList">
<ul id="slider"></ul>
</div>
</body>
`
```

- here I am getting images from my local directory and storing the images in a  list and displaying the same.
- how to get exif data of each image.(here some link I saw which have drog & drop options : [drag & drop image getting exif](http://html5.http://komplett.cc/code/chap_global/extract_exif_en.html) ),
- used js is : [exif.js](https://github.com/sanisoft/jQuery-fileExif/blob/master/jquery.exif.js)

Comment: I'm pretty sure your browser will crash if you load binary data for multiple images.

Comment: thanks @Dustin Hoffner , please can provide that code using of img tag or url get image meta data details .

Comment: Can you say which metadata you want to load?

Comment: image file -->rightClick-->properties -->Details-->Origin(Date taken) and camera(marker,model) and GPS(if possible) only

Comment: Hmm... I think this is nothing you should do on the client side. I would do this on serverside with nodejs or php, or whatever you want to use and send it via json to the client

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely possible using the new "blob" support in AJAX requests. I download videos in excess of 2GB using this method, to then store to disk using Filesystem APIs.

Here's a code snippet, taken from this overflow StackOverflow thread.

[Using jQuery's ajax method to retrieve images as a blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657184/using-jquerys-ajax-method-to-retrieve-images-as-a-blob)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        //this.response is what you're looking for
        handler(this.response);
        console.log(this.response, typeof this.response);
        var img = document.getElementById('img');
        var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        img.src = url.createObjectURL(this.response);
        }
    }
xhr.open('GET', 'http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png');
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.send();
```

However, this might not be the best approach - that's a lot of data to be loading just to get EXIF.

You might want to consider a backend element to this project. You could easily/quickly extract EXIF data (without having to load the whole image) and cache the results. You could also automatically create thumbnails to make your pages load quicker too.