# Blob sent through ajax receive through VB

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net, blob

I am kinda stuck right now. My VB script doesn't read the image blob, or does not get the file. I hope you can all help. Here is my code.

The image here is already in base64 and already being converted to blob and added to a form

```
var blob = dataURItoBlob(final_image.src);
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("objFile", blob, "image.jpeg");

$.ajax({
    url: 'UploadImage/ ImageFunction',
    data: { IDName: sessionStorage.IDName, CanvasImage: formData },
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST'
});
```

As you can see it here, it now being sent to the vb script. THe problem is that it doesnt read the blob file and doesnt save.

```
Function ImageFunction()
    Dim directory As String
    Dim objFile As HttpPostedFileBase = Request.Files("objFile")
    Dim counter As Integer = Request.Files.Count

    If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("temp\Pictures") Then
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("temp\Pictures")
    End If

    directory = "temp\Pictures\"

    If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(directory & Common.WebRequest.Data("IDName")) Then
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(directory & Common.WebRequest.Data("IDName"))
    End If

    If (Not objFile Is Nothing) Then
        objFile.SaveAs(directory & Common.WebRequest.Data("IDName") & "\" & Common.WebRequest.Data("IDName") & ".jpg")
    End If
End Function
```

Can someone lighten me if where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this question:

[Using jQuery's ajax method to retrieve images as a blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657184/using-jquerys-ajax-method-to-retrieve-images-as-a-blob)

If it is necesary to use ajax maybe you need to use native XMLHttprequest.

I hope helps!

Comment: nope.... I cant use the the link you give since I will be sending two data, first is the blob and the second one is the IDName.. besides both of then have to be sent

Comment: So you could make a form with a file type input and enctype=multipart/form-data for sending both the file and the IDName.

Comment: @jcarrerra you lost me there....