# jQuery: Set image to data from Post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Would like to get the data from a post request an pass it onto an img tag.
I know i could do it with an get request but i kinda need to use a post request to send the location of the file.

```
$.post('/getImage',{location: 'image.jpg'} ,function(image) {
    $('body').append('<img src=\'image\'></img>');
}
```

So is there any way to set the data from the post request to the img tag?
The post request works just so you know so i don't need any help setting that up

Comment: what you are returning from your server side?

Comment: can you post what is the content of data response

Comment: I'm using node.js and returning the content of the image itself. So what you see when you open an image in the editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the base64 encoding of the image and set the *image*'s *src* attribute like this:

```
$('body').append('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data + '" />');
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with node.js but a little searching showed that you can get base64 of a file like so:

`return new Buffer(fs.readFileSync(file)).toString('base64');`

Answer (score 1):

what kind of data returns from server in your callback?

```
you have two ways:
1) Convert file at server to base64, and create Image tag at client and set base64 to src
2) Return at server binary data, and use at client native xhrRequest, like in this post
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17682424/5138198