# How can I send an image back to client instead of telling a client where the image is hosted at? Is it even possible?

Tags: html, ajax, image, web

How can I send an image back to client instead of telling a client where the image is hosted at? Is it even possible?

I just do not want to let the client know where the image is hosted at.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085474/how-to-put-png-binary-data-into-an-img-tag-and-display-it-as-an-image

Comment: convert image into base64 or some other encoding and assign it to src tag instead of url of image