# How to get Image through ajax jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, image

I want to display image by ajax jquery in this way so is that possible?

```
$.ajax({  
    url: "c.jpeg",
    type :"get",
    dataType: "image/jpeg",

    success: function(data)
    {

      $("#myimg2").attr("src",data);
    }

   })
```

and this is the html

```
<body>
<img id="myimg2" ><br>
</body>
```

If that could be possible in some way. I want also to get the image from php file rather than directly jpeg file using this header.

```
header('content-type: image/jpeg');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657184/using-jquerys-ajax-method-to-retrieve-images-as-a-blob

Comment: @Hussein _"want to display image by ajax jquery"_ What is purpose of using ajax , jQuery ?

Comment: I want to update the image automatically by a poll function in ajax. And the image is coming from mysql database in php file, finally will receive that php file as an image file using   header('content-type: image/jpeg');

Comment: @Hussein How frequently should image be updated ?

Comment: It depends on database values and could be every 3 seconds or less

Comment: You don't need ajax for this, just use a regular image tag, and append a timestamp to the url every three seconds to update it.

Comment: One approach could include using `setTimeout` , `jQuery.ajax()` , return image as `data URI` from server , which would not require additional conversion to `objectURL` at browser ; could use existing `$("#myimg2").attr("src",data);`

Comment: @adeneo yeah you are right I have tried that but it is not working on java webView Android studio

Comment: @guest271314 I have the image comming from mysql database not server

Comment: @Hussein _"have the image comming from mysql database not server "_  Yes, "mysql database" is server to client browser ? Try converting image to `data URI` at database , return `data URI` string to `$.ajax()`

Comment: Could you please help me out with this coz I have no idea, what I am doing now is retrieve the image as blob and display it at the php using header('content-type: image/jpeg');

Comment: @Hussein See http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php , https://davidwalsh.name/data-uri-php ,  http://www.paulund.co.uk/convert-image-base64-php , https://gist.github.com/FlyingTopHat/3661056

Answer (score 3):

Please, try this. It works for me.

```js
$.ajax({
   url: "path/to/img.jpg",
   xhrFields: {
      responseType: 'blob'
   },
   success (data) {
      const url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      const src = url.createObjectURL(data);
      $('#image').attr('src', src);
   }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="image">
</div>
```