# JavaScript Handling different Content-Type in one request

Tags: javascript, json, http

In my project, there is a URL that normally responses an image with `Content-Type:image/png` that drawn by Java dynamically with user's data.

But sometime causes some reason, the user should not see the image or the image cannot be drawn with user's data. In this case, server will response JSON result that contains error info with
`Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8`

Is this possible to show the image while server response `Content-Type:image/png` otherwise to alert error info while Server response `Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8`?

I can handle either of the response content type, but struggling with  handling both of two content type in one request. is this possible?

---

**EDIT**

I tried using AJAX like

```
<img id="preview-img"/>

$.ajax({
    url: "/preview",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        if (!data.success) {
            alert(data.msg);
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("occur error");
    }
});
```

With above code, `alert(data.msg)` is available when Server response a JSON result with error message, but `alert("occur error")` will triggered when Server response correct Image.

And I retried with remove `dataType`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/preview",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        if (!data.success) {
            alert(data.msg);
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("occur error");
    }
});
```

Glad to see the `success` function is triggered whether Server response Image or JSON
But I don't know how to display Image with response data that looks like

```
ÿØÿàJFIFÿÛC     
 $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛC          
2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀ%a"ÿÄ    
ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br    
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ 
ÿÄµw!1AQaq"2B¡±Á    #3RðbrÑ
$4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ?÷ú(¢
......
```

A bunch of garbage.

---

And now I temporarily not to handle JSON result

```
<img id="preview-img"/>

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {
    $("#preview-img").attr("src", "/preview");
};
image.onerror = function() {
    alert("could not load image");
};

image.src = "/preview";
```

Comment: post code.. if you're using ajax you can.

Comment: Is the only reason to not have two endpoints (one for success/error status and one for picture, which is blank if error occurred) for efficiency?

Comment: @Pamblam code posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request fails with "dataType" set because JQuery tries to parse the response as JSON, but fails to do so if the server responded with an image. Therefore the error-callback is called.

The preferred solution, in my opinion, would be to set an HTTP code != 200 (e.g. 404 for not found) in case the image couldn't be served by the server. The error-callback would be called in that case and you can show an error-dialog the user. Otherwise you can proceed with displaying the image in the success-callback.

Regarding "I don't know how to display Image with response data that looks like" look here: [Using jQuery's ajax method to retrieve images as a blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657184/using-jquerys-ajax-method-to-retrieve-images-as-a-blob)

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it solved your problem. @Joe