# net::ERR_INVALID_URL when setting <img> src from $http.get result

Tags: angularjs, image, angularjs-directive, base64, src

I have a angular directive that works on img tags and loads the image dynamically as a base64 string. I use $http.get to load the image and set it into the img.src like this:

```
var onSuccess = function(response) {
  var data = response.data;
  element.attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + data);
};
var onError = function(response) {
  console.log("failed to load image");
};
scope.$watch('authSrc', function(newValue) {
  if (newValue) {
    $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: scope.authSrc,
      data: ""
    }).then(onSuccess, onError)
  }
});
```

after i set the src attribute, i get the **net::ERR_INVALID_URL** error.
The string that returns from the request looks like this:
IHDR����^tiDOT@(@@AMȯz�@IDATx��uw\�ٷ�o����G�B["...

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it to work will the help of [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657184/using-jquerys-ajax-method-to-retrieve-images-as-a-blob?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Trick was to use `responseType: "blob"`, and use URL/webkitURL `createObjectURL()`

Here's the full directive:

```
'use strict';

app.directive('authSrc',function ($http) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        authSrc: "="
      },
      link: function (scope, element) {
        var onSuccess = function(response) {
          var data = response.data;
          var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
          var src = url.createObjectURL(data);
          element.attr("src", src);
        };

        var onError = function(response) {
          console.log("failed to load image");
        };

        scope.$watch('authSrc', function(newValue) {
          if (newValue) {
            $http({
              method: "GET",
              url: scope.authSrc,
              responseType: "blob"
            }).then(onSuccess, onError)
          }
        });


      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I visited so many forums until I got to this!
THANK YOU FOR POSTING!

Answer (score 0):

Specify the responseType in your request, and you may have to disable default transforms that `$http` attempts on the data.

see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#overriding-the-default-transformations-per-request)

Comment: Thanks @tanenbring, doesn't look like a request transform problem, but response type helped me get to the answer, which i'll post in a sec

Answer (score 0):

My problem was specifying a zoom level after the base64 string '#zoom=90'