# JavaScript Blob returning broken PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, firefox, download, blob

I want to download *PDF* document with *JavaScript* and using *blob* as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link). If I download my PDF directly without *JS*, I receive a working *PDF*, but if I download it with *JavaScript* by using *blob* I cannot open my *PDF*. I tested it on *Mozilla Firefox 68.0.2 (64-Bit)* and *Google Chrome 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-Bit)* and it didn't work.

I tested different *Content-Type* headers, but wasn't able to resolve that issue. I tested with:

- text/plain
- text/html
- data:attachment/text
- application/pdf

My test server is returning those headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=document.pdf
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 577479
```

I tried also to set encoding to *UTF8*, but the result was the same.

I'm requesting it with *AJAX* (maybe problem is somewhere here?) and I'm using *jQuery v3.3.1*.

```
$.ajax({
    type    : "GET",
    url     : pdfDownloadURL,
    async   : true,
    success : function(blob) {

        var contentType = "attachment/pdf";

        try {
            var blob =  new Blob([blob], {type: contentType});
        } catch (e) {
            // The BlobBuilder API has been deprecated in favour of Blob, but older
            // browsers don't know about the Blob constructor
            // IE10 also supports BlobBuilder, but since the `Blob` constructor
            //  also works, there's no need to add `MSBlobBuilder`.
            var BlobBuilder = window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder;
            var bb = new BlobBuilder();
            bb.append(blob);
            var blob =  bb.getBlob(contentType);
        }

        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.target = "_blank";
        link.style = "display: none";
        link.download = "document2.pdf";
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
    },

    // ...

});
```

**document1.pdf** (*downloaded directly*)

[image: document1.pdf is fine]

**document2.pdf** (*downloaded using JavaScript blob method*)

[image: document2.pdf is broken]

I checked requests with [sniffing tool fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and server is returning always the same document, so the problem must be somewhere in my *JavaScript* part. As you can see in the red boxes - those bytes are the same, but then we have diffetent bytes, but I saw that server returned in both cases the same document, so this problem is only on the *client side*.

- Size of *document1.pdf* (OK): `577.479` bytes
- Size of *document2.pdf* (broken): `1.034.166` bytes

Then I try to open *document2.pdf* with *google chrome 76.0.3809.132, 64-Bit* and it fails.

[image: google chrome PDF viewer]

Is there a problem with my version of *jQuery* (in that *AJAX* part)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17682424/1561413

Comment: @crayze ok, it works, thank you! problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution to this problem: [Using jQuery's ajax method to retrieve images as a blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657184/using-jquerys-ajax-method-to-retrieve-images-as-a-blob)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17682424

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url:'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465101108990-e5eac17cf76d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ%3D%3D&s=471ae675a6140db97fea32b55781479e',
        cache:false,
        xhr:function(){// Seems like the only way to get access to the xhr object
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.responseType= 'blob'
            return xhr;
        },
        success: function(data){
            var img = document.getElementById('img');
            var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            img.src = url.createObjectURL(data);
        },
        error:function(){

        }
    });
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="img" width=100%>
```