# How to download generated python docx file using Ajax

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, python-docx

I need to get some data from my template and send it back to my Django function using ajax, create a docx file and download it

Django Function

```
def download_docx_file(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        language = request.GET['lang']
        data = request.GET['data']
        converter = {'data': 'This is the real data'}
        document = Document()
        document.add_heading(f'{language} -- {converter[data]}', 0)
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=download.docx'
        document.save(response)
        return response
    return HttpResponse("hello")
```

AJAX

```
$("#dwnBtn").click(function(){
$.ajax({
url : "docx/",
type:"GET",
data : { lang : 'lang', data:'data' },
success : function(data){
console.log(data)

}
})
});
```

I am getting sth like the below response from AJAX response:

Response console.log(data)

�ܝBp��݂�;|C�ھ�w������=O���]]�%�N�����#+�reup����������Y������̉�J����3)� O��C����F�M�P�&�����rA�@��7T.��z(%h��x�x0�0Z�-i��%q�e�M�����i�"�c��-/��j��齔/ļL瞄�0� �� >�o��[��6  멆�n��s�$�
�#>˘ '��wT�� ���3�36DK�+�̓�t6 ��r��sA:���x�<>n������'U��RLqA+���ݺ�BM��:4ĞP�}���:�}ߣP����?F)�9-�W0���2�{x��#2v8N.$V�>X=/�+�c}���ּ�\y���*�J\��
���90�T�L� 3p���*Sfj(���PWWz��O�s�9]&����iO|�9�;�5��ʘdW�cl% �%;����u���%[�5������Q]$��[L>���yXg�9��2+&,iFs�Q�����u�.�E(�>W��+��M ؟E������i|���k�k�c蟴CcG�j��4s|x �F1�}��Y��,29�0M=-O����m\L��y��^On^���\���u��a���F9:zc�Sy�-�g��fu�n�C�T:{ ��4&/ ��LM9�98� �&Pnc�!��m�r�~��)74�04��0�0������M�~"��.ikjG��M�

how can I save this binary data as a .docx file?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Does it have to be ajax? You can just do a `location = 'docx/?lang=lang&data=data';`

Comment: in fact, the value inside the data is more complicated than a simple string. That's why I don't use URLs.

Comment: You can use `$.param` to convert your complicated data to a url param string. `location = 'docx/?'+$.param(complicated_data_object);

Comment: Thanks Musa I did it as you suggest                                                          
window.location ="{% url 'my_url' 'lang' 'data' %}".replace(/data/, JSON.stringify(arr));              and it kinda solved my issue. However, I'm still wondering is it possible to convert that binary data?

Comment: You can look at this answer to see how to get the data as a blob https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657184/using-jquerys-ajax-method-to-retrieve-images-as-a-blob/17682424?r=SearchResults&s=3|2.3184#17682424