Downloaded PDF shows blank pages when pulling from SQL db
I'm pulling PDF files from a SQL table,  and then wanting to show the PDF in a new window rather than download to the user's computer. I get the data successfully,  but when I try to view the PDF I get blank pages.  The right number of pages shows but content is blank.  Can't understand what's happening. Here is my code:
        var ms = new Date();
        var params = "action=DownloadFile2&ms=" + ms.getTime() + "&file_id=" + file_id;
        var url = urlPath + params;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            method: "POST",
            responseType: "blob",
            url: url,
            
            success: function (data) {
                var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                window.open(fileURL, '', "height=1000, width=2000");
            }

Code behind: If IsDBNull(dt) = True Then Exit Sub
    Dim filename As String
    filename = Trim(dt.Rows(0)("Name").ToString())

    Dim filetype As String
    filetype = Trim(dt.Rows(0)("File_Type").ToString())

    Dim encodedBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(CType(dt.Rows(0)("Data"), Byte())))

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public")
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0")
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & filename)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = False
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", encodedBytes.Length.ToString())

    Dim outputStream As Stream = HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream

    outputStream.Write(encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.Length)
    outputStream.Flush()
    outputStream.Close()

I tried to open the PDF in a new window, I just get blank pages.  One document showed page 1 and rest blank.

try removing  { type: 'application/pdf' } from  var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });, use just var file = new Blob([data])

I'm not sure responseType : "blob" is valid. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657184/using-jquerys-ajax-method-to-retrieve-images-as-a-blob also seems to imply that's the case, too.

Instead of using an .aspx page to serve the data, use an .ashx handler. There are many ways trying to use an .aspx page can mess it up where an .ashx handler will simply make work.

(Also, Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(...) is a waste of effort. Can you see why?)
